# Why I can't use ctx.body in the callback of save()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, koa

I can use `ctx.body` in `find()`'s callback:

```js
router.post("/register/isNameUsed", async (ctx, next) => {
    let username = ctx.request.body.username;
    await userInfo.find({ username: username }, function(err, doc) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            if (doc.length > 0) {
                ctx.body = { isNameUsed: true };
            } else {
                ctx.body = { isNameUsed: false };
            }
        }
    });

    await next();
});
```

But I can't use it in `save()`'s callback:

```js
router.post("/register", async (ctx, next) => {
    let username = ctx.request.body.name;
    let password = ctx.request.body.password;
    var ui = new userInfo({
        username,
        password
    });
    await ui.save(function(err, doc) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            ctx.body = { registerSuccess: true };//It doesn't work
        }
    });
    await next();
});
```

The code runs successfully，just the `ctx.body` doesn't work, why?

Comment: Not sure, but this might be due to javascript's weird scoping issues. try converting the callback to use an arrow function and see if it works. IE `await ui.save((err, doc) => { if (err) console.log(err); } else { ctx.body = { registerSuccess: true }; });`

Comment: Still not working...

Answer (score 0):

OK，I changed my code to this:

```js
router.post("/register", async (ctx, next) => {
    let username = ctx.request.body.name;
    let password = ctx.request.body.password;

    var ui = new userInfo({
        username,
        password
    });

    try {
        let insertRes = await ui.save();
        ctx.body = { registerSuccess: true };
    } catch (error) {
        ctx.body = { registerSuccess: false };
    }

    await next();
});
```

Then the `ctx.body` worked.

And I'll never write `ctx.body` in the callback, it's so queasily...

But I still don't know why the `ctx.body` can work in the `find()`'s callback but not in the `save()`s?

Comment: Because callbacks are handled *after* the function completes. Don't mix async/await and callbacks.

Comment: Hey @takeItIzzy welcome to stackoverflow

I think this problem is not related to `ctx` or `koa`, it's about how mongoose save function works, I think you should either remove the await (in your original post) and handle consequence of the save function inside the callback or do you like you did in this answer and call it as an async function using await or chaining using .then, .catch, etc.

Also I am not sure if await before next is necessary.

Comment: FWIW, this code snippet looks cleaner and that's how I would do it, also as a general architecture tip, look into koa's cool global error handling https://github.com/koajs/koa/wiki/Error-Handling